# Convert 1K,1M to 1000, 1000 000 in excel with Text function and convert to number

Tags: excel

I want to convert some values that are in this format (€77M) to this one (77000000), I have searched for some functions to convert and the only one working it's the `TEXT` function, the problem is the text function returns a text and I'm not able to sum all the values using `pivotTable`, is there a way that I can convert the text as number to do the `sum`?
The formula I'm using is

```
 =TEXT( IF(RIGHT(L2;1)="k";VALUE(LEFT(L2;LEN(L2)-1))*1000;IF(RIGHT(L2;1)="m";VALUE(LEFT(L2;LEN(L2)-1))*10^6;L2)); "###0.00")
```

the L2 it's the cell that contains the (€77M).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TEXT` function here is just formating the number resulted from the function inside to text.. so you can simply delete the `TEXT` function to have a number that you can use with `sum` function

```
=IF(RIGHT(L2;1)="k";VALUE(LEFT(L2;LEN(L2)-1))*1000;IF(RIGHT(L2;1)="m";VALUE(LEFT(L2;LEN(L2)-1))*10^6;L2))
```